# Why does deleteB() not deleting the last element in the Linked List?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below code. I have created 2 python files. The first file contains class Linked List , which contains all required Linked List functions. The second file contains an infinite loop which takes input for operations on a linked list. In deleteB() fn I am trying to delete the last node. It is coming till the last node but not deleting it. Whereas if am using the 'prev Node' variable it is able to delete it?

File1:LinkedList.py

class LinkedList:

```
 def __init__(self,head=None):
        self.head=head

 def deleteB(self):

    if self.head is None:
        print("List empty")
        return None


    if self.head.next is None:
        print("Deleted Item is:", self.head.info)  #This is working
        self.head=None
        return None

    cur = self.head.next
    while cur.next:                        # prev=cur
        cur = cur.next
    print("Deleted Item is:", cur.info)   #Till Here it is working and 
                                           sending the last info
    cur = None                            #prev.next=None
    return self.head


  def display(self):

       if self.head is None:
            print("List empty")
            return
       temp = self.head
       print("head", end="")
       while temp is not None:
          print("->", temp.info, end="")
          temp = temp.next
       print()
```

File2:

```
 from DataStructures import LinkedList as ld

 ob = ld.LinkedList()
 while 1:
     ch = int(input("Enter 1 : Insertion 2:Deletion Back  
                   3:Display  5:exit"))
      if ch==1:
         ob.head=ob.insertf()
      elif ch == 2:
         ob.head = ob.deleteB()
      elif ch==3:
         ob.display()
      else:
         exit()
```

EXCPECTED OUTPUT(Last Line of Output.I am getting this if I use the prev variable which is commented) :

head-> 66-> 55-> 34

Enter 1 : Insertion  2:Deletion Front 3:Deletion Back  4:Display  5:exit 3

Deleted Item is: 34

Enter 1 : Insertion  2:Deletion Front 3:Deletion Back  4:Display  5:exit 4

head-> 66-> 55

GETTING OUTPUT:

head-> 66-> 55-> 34

Enter 1 : Insertion  2:Deletion Front 3:Deletion Back  4:Display  5:exit 3

Deleted Item is: 34

Enter 1 : Insertion  2:Deletion Front 3:Deletion Back  4:Display  5:exit 4

head-> 66-> 55-> 34

Answer (score 0):

With `cur = None` you reset a local variable `cur`, but you do not unlink the last item of the list from its predecessor.

Instead do

```
cur = self.head
while cur.next.next:  # the next is not the last one
    cur = cur.next
cur.next =  None  # unlink the last
```

This will also handle the two-items list case.

Answer (score 0):

`cur = None` is setting the local variable `cur` (that you used to find the last node) equal to `None`. That doesn't do anything to the reference to the last node in the list. The previous node still has a reference to it. You need to set `prev.next = None` to break that link.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `cur = None` will only set the local variable `cur` to `None`. The reference from the previous node still exists and points to the node you wish to delete.

If you don't want to have the references to cur and prev, you can change your while loop to something like this:

```
cur = self.head
while cur.next.next:
    cur = cur.next

cur.next = None
```